# Proof that language is not context-free.

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Is this the appropriate way to show that this language is not context-free?

> Given the language $L$ containing the words $1$, $101$, $101001$,
>   $1010010001$, where each word $L_n$ is of the form
>   $10^110^21...10^{n-1}10^n1$.
>
> Assume that $L$ is context-free, and as such that there is some $p$
>   which is the pumping length for $L$.
>
> Consider $s = L_{p-1}$. It is trivial to show that $|s| \geq p$.
>
> By the pumping lemma, we should be able write $s$ in the form $s =
> > wvxyz$ where $|vxy| \leq p$ and $|vy| \geq 1$ such that $wv^ixy^iz \in
> > L$ for all $i$.
>
> As $i = 0$, being a possible number of repeats, would give $wxz \in
> > L$.
>
> Therefore, as $L$ only permits deletion from the tail of words we
>   can derive that $x = \lambda$ and $z = \lambda$.
>
> Also we can see that either $v$ or $y$ must equal $0^{p-1}1$. We can
>   confirm that $|vxy| \leq p$ holds for this.
>
> However, $i = 2$ is also a possible number of repeats, but would
>   result in a word that ends $0^{p-1}10^{p-1}1$ and therefore that is
>   not contained in $L$.
>
> Therefore we have a contradiction, and $L$ is not context-free.

Thankyou for your comments. Yes, this is homework.

Comment: See also [this question on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/98).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track (certainly avoiding the most common fallacies in using the pumping lemma) but the logic is incomplete.  It's not quite true that $L$ only permits deletion from the tail of words.  Deletion from near the tail is also possible, such as 101001<s>00010</s>0001.

There will no doubt be more than one way to complete the argument.  One simple option is to divide into two cases depending on whether $vy$ contains any 1, and make deductions about the distribution of spacings between pairs of 1s in either case.

Comment: Thanks, excellent point there. I beleive that there is a solution by using $0^i10^{p-1-i}$.

Comment: Yes, using $x = \lambda$, $z = 0^i1$, with either $v$ or $y$ being $0^i10^{p-1-i}$ for some $0 \leq i < p - 1$ I think I can cover all the possible deletions.